# Microsoft Flow Custom API Authentication

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

I have created a Custom API in Microsoft's Power Apps. For creating this API, i have uploaded swagger.json file for the API's.The API's support Basic Authentication.
After creating API, a connection has been established for the same.
While using the created API in Microsoft Flow I am getting Invalid Connection error. Any ideas how to debug this or how to create a valid connection ?

Answer (score 0):

Invalid connection error usually comes when the url is not accessible by Microsoft flow. Make sure the API call is hitting your server while testing the custom connector.

If it is hitting correctly, debug the request coming in and make sure the authentication format is correct and the headers are matched.

Answer (score 0):

Always test endpoints in the browser and Postman first before moving to PowerApps/Flow.

My work flow is:

- Hit the (GET) endpoint in the browser first. If the web service is hosted on-prem, ensure you're on the VPN and have the Data Gateway installed correctly. Does the service respond?
- Hit the (GET or POST) endpoint in Postman. Does the service respond?
- Copy the Request/Response url/schema(s) into a new PowerApps custom connector and create a connection. Does the service respond?
- Add the Custom Connector to PowerApps. Close and open the app to allow the Connection.
- Collect the custom API call. Any errors?
- Visualize the response in a Gallery
- Prosper!

Here is a [video detailing the end-to-end creation of a Custom Connector](https://youtu.be/-wQljWG35zM?t=592) in PowerApps.